# Database with Blob field unknown format. How to extract?

Tags: sqlite, blob, reverse-engineering

the story behind this is a bit funny. I had a diary on ios, the app isn't available anymore so I switched to another app. Could backup the database.

I know the column where the text is stored. Unfortunately, it is in a blob format. The database is a sqllite file.

Is there a way to find out what the true format is and somehow convert it back to text? At the beginning I thought it's just a sql command but I wasn't successful.

Do you have any Idea or an appraoch how to solve that ?

PS:

That is the beginning of one blob file: 'É' ¥I±00n'.
And here is the same in hex:14C9271E2005A549B130308E8F6ECF69A74A

Could only put the beginning here, since I really don't know what is written there.

Comment: Well blob is a valid format for sqlite. https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html I think you mean that you don't know what data is stored in the blob?

Comment: Exactly! I know that text is stored there. And I even know the text for some rows. But I don’t know how the text is encoded in blob.

Comment: You need to post the beginning of the data stored in that blob in order for ppl to help you. Maybe it's a know one. If not, they take the data - put it in a file and run it through `file` or `binwalk`.

Comment: Sure you are right! I added the beginning of the file as I could see through the database. Also added the beginning of the hex representation since the binary looked strange.

Comment: Well I'm not fumiliar with iOS apps but you need some kind of reflection. They can store their classes in blobs as well and you can't just think you got their models out of it.

Comment: Try running `strings YourFile` to see if it can extract some ASCII text strings.